# New to learning CSS Animation! Animation is changing color, but not moving to the left

Tags: html, css

This is the code that I have so far, the color changes like it is supposed to. But the animation for moving does not work and stays in the same position. Not sure what I am missing.

```
  div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  postion: relative;
  }
  #square {
     animation-name: first;
     animation-duration: 4s;
     }

  @keyframes first {
  0% {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
50% {
  background-color: green;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;

}
100% {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: -25px;
  left: -25px;
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Preston G., welcome to SO!! We need code including HTML/CSS/JS to trace your errors, please post a [reprex]....

Comment: Please share your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You've make a simple mistake in your code.

On the div selector, you write the position selector as **postion** for this reason the animation can't work.

Here is the working code:

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

#square {
  animation-name: first;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes first {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: green;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: yellow;
    top: -25px;
    left: -25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <h1>Hello World.</h1>
</div>
```